# Running Live Migration using Custom QEMU build

Tags: qemu, virsh

I am trying to understand the migration code in QEMU, and for that I've tried to build QEMU from scratch and I am running/starting VM using this commands

`x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -enable-kvm -drive if=virtio,file=test.qcow2,cache=none -cdrom ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso` -> for creating VM for the first time

`x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -enable-kvm -drive if=virtio,file=test.qcow2,cache=none` -> this for subsequently running VMs

Now I want to try and migrate a VM from one machine to other both running QEMU built from source. I want to do it without using `virsh`.

Or else I want to try to install virsh and then use migration, but how do I install virt-manager that works with custom build of QEMU?

I've tried doing live migration by installing QEMU/KVM, virt-manager from ubuntu repos, and it works fine. But I didn't find any way to do it if you are building QEMU from source.